# Which one is more performant in terms of CPU . `Option.fold()()` or `Option.map().getOrElse()`?

Tags: scala, performance, benchmarking, jmh

I am trying to know in terms of `time per op` which method is faster.

Instinctively, I would say that `fold` is faster as it "seems" to not instantiate extra `Option`, cf implementation:

```
@inline final def fold[B](ifEmpty: => B)(f: A => B): B =
  if (isEmpty) ifEmpty else f(this.get)
```

```
@inline final def map[B](f: A => B): Option[B] =
  if (isEmpty) None else Some(f(this.get))
```

However I tried to profile using `jmh` to profile `allocation rate` and `time` using the following code:

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations._

@State(Scope.Benchmark)
@BenchmarkMode(Array(Mode.AverageTime))
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Fork(value = 1, jvmArgsAppend = Array("-Djmh.stack.lines=3"))
@Threads(1)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 3, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 3, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
class OptionBench {
  val someOption = Some(2)
  val noneOption = None

  def fold(option: Option[Int]) = option.fold(0)(_ * 2)

  def map(option: Option[Int]) = option.map(_ * 2).getOrElse(0)

  @Benchmark
  def someNothing = someOption

  @Benchmark
  def someFold = fold(someOption)

  @Benchmark
  def noneFold = fold(noneOption)

  @Benchmark
  def someMap = map(someOption)

  @Benchmark
  def noneMap = map(noneOption)
}
```

I got the following results :

```
Benchmark                                    Mode  Cnt   Score    Error   Units
OptionBench.noneFold                         avgt    5   2,214 ±  0,068   ns/op
OptionBench.noneFold:·gc.alloc.rate          avgt    5  ≈ 10⁻⁴           MB/sec
OptionBench.noneFold:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     avgt    5  ≈ 10⁻⁶             B/op
OptionBench.noneFold:·gc.count               avgt    5     ≈ 0           counts
OptionBench.noneMap                          avgt    5   2,373 ±  0,106   ns/op
OptionBench.noneMap:·gc.alloc.rate           avgt    5  ≈ 10⁻⁴           MB/sec
OptionBench.noneMap:·gc.alloc.rate.norm      avgt    5  ≈ 10⁻⁶             B/op
OptionBench.noneMap:·gc.count                avgt    5     ≈ 0           counts
OptionBench.someFold                         avgt    5   3,183 ±  0,282   ns/op
OptionBench.someFold:·gc.alloc.rate          avgt    5  ≈ 10⁻⁴           MB/sec
OptionBench.someFold:·gc.alloc.rate.norm     avgt    5  ≈ 10⁻⁶             B/op
OptionBench.someFold:·gc.count               avgt    5     ≈ 0           counts
OptionBench.someMap                          avgt    5   2,994 ±  0,181   ns/op
OptionBench.someMap:·gc.alloc.rate           avgt    5  ≈ 10⁻⁴           MB/sec
OptionBench.someMap:·gc.alloc.rate.norm      avgt    5  ≈ 10⁻⁶             B/op
OptionBench.someMap:·gc.count                avgt    5     ≈ 0           counts
OptionBench.someNothing                      avgt    5   2,258 ±  0,085   ns/op
OptionBench.someNothing:·gc.alloc.rate       avgt    5  ≈ 10⁻⁴           MB/sec
OptionBench.someNothing:·gc.alloc.rate.norm  avgt    5  ≈ 10⁻⁶             B/op
OptionBench.someNothing:·gc.count            avgt    5     ≈ 0           counts
```

Unfortunately I am not able to draw any conclusions of this. Am I doing my profiling wrong ? Which one is "faster" ?

Comment: Probably the **JIT** will inline all that, also if you really care about the CPU performance, probably **Opyion** would be pretty slow compared to just returning `null` _(especially for primitives)_, and even **Scala** as a language and the **JVM** as a platform. The reason for using **Option** is for readability and correctness of the code, and as such, I would recommend you to just use the one which is more readable and maintainable for you.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Actually I am in a use case where a few `ns` might make a difference. I also need to use a jvm language (for `Spark` compatibility).Thanks for your comment, I will dig the use of `null`, thank you

Comment: The only concern with map is it allocates new object. If you only benchmark with one object, it's not gonna make a difference. Try to do it with millions of map in one test, and you might spot a difference. GC overhead is theoretically more prone in that case

Comment: @texasbruce, probably, I already tried with `10 000` maps stored in a list, but I was afraid to also compare the `traverse` at the same time, which might lead in false conclusions. But maybe to profile `gc` only it might work ! I will give it a try with several missions. Thanks for your insight !